# Can't understand why this MySQL function won't work correctly past 12

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

For some reason the following mySQL function only works up to position 12 for me

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');

SELECT SPLIT_STR(column, ",", **2**) from table
```

I have a loop running to increment this function automatically so I can cover large fields that contain more than 18 values delimited by commas. Once I hit 13 on the pos argument in this function I receive a cut off partial value. After 13 I receive empty values back. Any ideas what could be causing this? Maybe some setting for the row is affecting this?

Comment: `LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1))` looks suspicious with delim being VARCHAR(12) and delim hitting 13

Comment: That was my first thought and I tried changing it but saw no difference. I'll try changing it again maybe phpmyadmin didn't save it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was an issue with the varchar. I had previously had them set to 255 but I discovered I had rows containing 360 characters do I set them to 1000 and it fixed the issue.